# unicode in filenames when unzipping in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, unzip

I have this unzipping function which is is using a .NET library (compression), but the problem is I am having some unicode problems in the file name for example "µ" is being converted to "æ"

is there a solution to this problem without using other unzipping libraries because I am limited to some licenses and found this one suite me the best

```
 using System.IO.Compression;

 private void Unzip()
    {
        try
        {
            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

            // unzip update
            using (ZipArchive archive = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.OpenRead(ZipFile))
            {

                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                {
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(appPath, entry.FullName);
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(entry.Name))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!entry.Name.Equals("Updater.exe"))
                        {
                            entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath,true);

                        }
                    }
                }

                //  UpdateProgress(((float)s.Position / (float)fileStream.Length) * 100F);
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(extraWaitMilliseconds); //don't go too fast

            }
            UnzipFinished();  //*********^

        }            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        UnzipFailed(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I love how you say "this one suits you the best" even though it clearly doesn't suit you that good (and hence the question here).

Comment: I love how you interpreted it your way..
it suits me the best when it comes to the licensing issue that I am limited to.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer from GvS is not quite correct. It works in the specific case where the zip file uses cp850. If it using a different encoding, you will have to specify that instead. See Adriano's answer for background information. But based on your example, cp850 may be the right choice in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I read your restriction about the license, but I think, you will find this article on codeproject useful.

It explains how to use windows internal ZIP with a dot net wrapper, and the discussion thread in this link helped me with special characters in file/direcory names.

[Link "C# Use Zip Archives without External Libraries"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209731/Csharp-use-Zip-archives-without-external-libraries?msg=4284288#xx4284288xx) Using the title as google search items brings me the article on top position. Basically its a wrapper about the MS.Internal.IO.Zip.